# How to upload NPM executable file to nexus server

Tags: node.js, executable, nexus

I have nodejs application, and I already successfully uploaded my project to my nexus server. But sadly, I upload only code, but no executable file. 
This is my part of package.json. What should I change?

```
"publishConfig": {
    "registry": "URL"
 },
```

Comment: "publishConfig" : {
  "registry" : "http://localhost:8081/repository/npm-internal/"
},    // as documented here:  https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Node+Packaged+Modules+and+npm+Registries#NodePackagedModulesandnpmRegistries-PublishingnpmPackages

Comment: thats what I have, and meant by the URL